# Wifi drops (doesn't disconnect) on large downloads Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, 18.04, realtek-wireless

I've looked at a bunch of solutions but nothing I seem to do fixes my problem.

My wifi drops (doesn't disconnect) when downloading large files using any program. The dongle is a Belkin N300 (F9L1002v1) with power saving turned off. It's not the router. Normally I have to disconnect and reconnect the dongle for it to start working again.

```
lshw -class network

 *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:feaf8000-feafffff memory:fe800000-fe9fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5761 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 10
       serial: d0:67:e5:e7:39:42
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 firmware=5761-v3.73 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:24 memory:febf0000-febfffff memory:febe0000-febeffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:4
       logical name: wlxc05627e08e22
       serial: c0:56:27:e0:8e:22
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8712u ip=192.168.1.39 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn

lsusb       

Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 050d:845a Belkin Components F7D2101 802.11n Surf & Share Wireless Adapter v1000 [Realtek RTL8192SU]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS880 Host Bridge
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Dell Device 9602
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (ext gfx port 0)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 4)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 3c)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS880 [Radeon HD 4200]
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM5761 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)

dmesg | grep -i firmware

[  117.906958] usb 1-4: r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
[22626.863271] usb 1-4: r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
[86259.292461] usb 1-4: r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
[115481.231040] usb 1-4: r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
[122922.556929] usb 1-4: r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
[171238.283843] usb 1-4: r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
[171623.085302] usb 1-4: r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
[173323.454846] usb 1-4: r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
[174063.517332] usb 1-4: r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin
```

"

Comment: Please take a look at the output of `journalctl  $(type -p NetworkManager)`

Comment: it's a huge log going back hours, is there anyway for me to limit it? Here it is [pastbin](https://pastebin.com/raw/J05QHiaR)

Comment: Read `man journalctl`, and you can do things like `journalctl  $(type -p NetworkManager) --since='-4 hours'`. I no longer read megabytes of logs without fininancial persuasion, and maybe not even then.

Comment: Reading man pages should have been my first thought. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue in Ubuntu 20.04. The adapter worked fine for a while, then would drop (large downloads reliably caused the issue). Also unloading the module (modprobe -r r8712u) would hang. I could "fix" the problem by using either of the following two procedures:

- Unplugging the usb adapter and re-plugging.

OR

- Unloading the module (modprobe -r r8712u) and reloading (modprode r8712u).

I fixed the problem by disabling the "ht_enable" parameter on the r8712u module. I don't know what the module is and I can't find any reference material for the r8712u module parameters. I also disabled power_mgnt since many people seem to have issue with that (I haven't tried re-enabling it).

You can use this command to check the current values for the modules parameters:

```
systool -vm r8712u
```

Here's the command to disable the ht_enable and power_mgnt parameters:

```
echo "options r8712u power_mgnt=0 ht_enable=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/r8712u.conf
```

You will then have to reboot or reload the module like so

```
modprobe -vr r8712u
modprode -v r8712u
```

This is the [forum post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2347800&p=13588307#post13588307) that lead me to try this. Hopefully this helps someone.